# QSound error - unresolved externals

Tags: c++, qt

Although this question has been asked many times, there was no solution for this problem. Another "problem" is I'm German, so excuse my bad English.

I'm currently working on a Qt5 widget application, in Qt Creator 4.3.1.
It's a timer application, requesting input (hours, minutes, seconds) to let the application how long to count down.

Now I'm implementing a acoustic warning function, so when the countdown is done, it should play a sound. That sound is included in a Qt resource file.

The code in the timer countdown function is:

```
QSound::play(":/music/beep.wav");
```

The error (it's in German) is the following:

> mainwindow.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes
>   externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl
>   QSound::play(class QString const &)"
>   (__imp_?play@QSound@@SAXABVQString@@@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void
>   __thiscall MainWindow::on_run_clicked(void)" (?on_run_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)".

(in english:)

> *mainwindow.obj:-1: Error: LNK2019: Reference to non-solved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl
>   QSound::play(class QString const &)"
>   (__imp_?play@QSound@@SAXABVQString@@@Z)" in function ""private: void
>   __thiscall MainWindow::on_run_clicked(void)" (?on_run_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)".*

The strange thing is, I've added the

```
QT       += multimedia
```

flag inside the .pro file. That's the reason why the other solutions from here didn't work.

Does anyone know what to do? My OS is Windows 7, 64-bit.

I would be glad to get a good tip from anyone.

**EDIT**

It helped to run qmake to rebuild the Makefile.

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html

Comment: qmake: `QT += multimedia`

Comment: @AlexanderVX Ehm, what did I do in the .pro file ... :-)